# SearchView in android Shows nothing in the list

Tags: android, searchview

This code is not working properly. Whenever i search for an item starts with a capital letter it shows nothing in the list. It only shows letters starting with small alphabets.

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        String userinput= s.toLowerCase();
        List<MultipleFoodWraper> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(MultipleFoodWraper name :multipleFoodWraperArrayList) {
            if (name.getName().toString().contains(userinput)) {
                newlist.add(name);
            }

            adapter.updatelist(newlist);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know where the name variable gets initialized with value or what it holds, but shouldn't this, ```s.toLowerCase();``` be the main cause of your issue?

Comment: Have you tried `name.getName().toString().toLowerCase()` when comparing?

Comment: @LeoPelozo  Thanku so so much it works 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting `name` to lowercase does the trick
 `name.getName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(userinput)`